# git diff not working on a bare repo, post-receive hook

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, git-post-receive

I am working on a post-receive hook on a bare repo.
I want to get the file names that are changed and pushed in this bare repo (only the latest one).
To get it i am using this command.

`git diff --name-only HEAD^`

This gives me error when I push to bare repo.

```
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I got that there is no worktree in bare repo so this command fails but how to get this run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the command you are looking for is `git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD`. This will compare the "current" commit with the commit before it.

Comment: This gives `remote : fatal : Not a git repository` on bare repo. On non-bare repo it works fine. I need this to be run on post-receive hook of my central bare repo.

Comment: Hmmm, that is a very puzzling error, since it definitely _is_ a git repository (otherwise you wouldn't have gotten the original error in your question). And I tried the command out on my bare repo and it worked fine, albeit not as part of a hook. Out of curiosity, can you run the command on your bare repo from the command line, i.e. not as part of a hook?

Comment: @Foolish I don't get any error with the above command in a bare repo.  Maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch Yes the solution you suggested is working fine in bare repo but not working as part of hook because when I run hook I am on ".git" directory, while this works directly because it's on bare repo directory.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch This is working fine in hook too,  don't know what was the issue.. Thanks for help.

Comment: This should be `git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD`

Comment: Thanks, @Foolish, I have updated the answer for future searchers.